# Problem with @import sass files in Vuej.s

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, sass, relative-path

I currently changed the way my scss folder structure to 7-1 pattern which is introduced at https://sass-guidelin.es/#architecture .
I moved my old scss files and fonts to 7-1 pattern folder, like what you see in the below picture:

[image]

I really dont understand why does it shows me this error:

[image]

How should i really fix this problem?

.......

**update**

when i change the file name from style.scss to style.css and use `@import "~@vue/../../src/assets/icomoon/style.css";`
 it seems to work, but i don't know why when it was a style.scss , it didn't work and why i should use ~@vue/../../src ,  what is the problem here?

here is the reprex:
https://github.com/SeyyedKhandon/sass_import

Answer (score 0):

try **@/** before your path like this:

```
 @import '@/assets/test/test.scss'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't fixed it, and it says the same error

Answer (score 0):

The `~` refers to the `/node_modules/` relative path: don’t use it here. Having a look at your code, you just need to add `import "./assets/icomoon/style.css"` in `main.ts` IMHO. Is it an installed Node module or, as I guessed, a file manually saved in the assets directory?

Comment: did you checked the reprex  https://github.com/SeyyedKhandon/sass_import ?

Comment: yes, but `main.ts` doesn’t import any CSS right now: being Ico Moon under `/assets`, you have to get rid of both `~` and `@`; see [https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#url-transform-rules](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#url-transform-rules) for more. If you add one of those symbols, Vue CLI looks for a file under the `/node_modules/` path.

Comment: I dont want to add css to main.ts, i just wanted to add it in app.vue file, so when i use @ import "./icomoon/style.css";  or @ import "icomoon/style.css"; as you said, it will tell me "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './icomoon/style.css' in 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\sass_import\src'"

Comment: you should… because that’s how it should work: that’s not Sass, nor SCSS, but plain CSS; anyway, if you want to do otherwise, in App.vue you can still `@import "assets/icomoon/style.css"` (without `src/`) under the `<style>` tag, I guess.

Comment: I know i can use it in app.vue, but the problem is it's not a good idea to have your all assets be added directly in app.vue and its good to be added in main.scss and just add main.scss file. do you have any idea about fixing this problem?